# Dead code on a nested for loop that returns a boolean

Tags: java, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to complete an exercise that we received in class. The solution was not nor will ever be posted since it is not evaluated. I can't seem to figure it out. When I run this code I get a warning for dead code. Which makes sense because my code seems to not permit to iterate through the second sub-array. So, when all elements are the same for the first sub-array even when they aren't for the second the method returns true. Any idea of how to fix this? I'm pretty lost at this point.

```
public class Warmup2 {


public static void main(String[] args) { 
    int[][] arr = {{1,1},{6,6,7}};
    System.out.println(subArraySame(arr));
}
//method that takes a 2D-array and checks if the elements of the subarrays are all the same
public static boolean subArraySame(int[][] arr) {

    for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<arr[i].length-1; j++) {
            if(arr[i][j]==arr[i][j+1]) {
                return true;
            } else {
              return false;  
            }
        }
      }return false;

   }

 }
```

Comment: @NiVeR aren't {1,1} and {6,6,7} subarrays of arr? respectively at arr[0] and arr[1]?

Comment: you should try to understand the difference between `return`, `break` and `continue` in a `for` loop in Java. Then the rest should be clear and can be solved by yourself I'm sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want this:

```
public static boolean subArraySame(int[][] arr) {
    for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length-1; j++) {
            if(arr[i][j] != arr[i][j+1]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

which returns true only if every subarray consists of equal items. 
Your code terminated the loop at the 1st iteration because the `if/else` statements both contained a `return`.

Comment: Yes! thank you! that indeed works! If you don't mind me asking, why do you think this (which is more or less the opposite of what I did) works and not my original method? How come I can reach all the code here but not as I did before? Thanks again!

Comment: If you read my last edit: your code terminated the loop at the 1st iteration because the if/else statements both contained a  return.

Comment: No, every "row" consists of equal elements

Comment: Right, I was thinking too far ahead and lost the focus on what exactly the question was xD

Answer (score 1):

The dead code refers to the increment (`j++`) of the second loop. This will be never reached since the statement:

```
if(arr[i][j]==arr[i][j+1]) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;  
}
```

returns immediately at the first point it is met, i.e. when `j=0`, hence `j++` will never get reached.